# Contact Reference Field Import & Batch update

Tags: import, contact-reference

How can someone import or do a batch update using a profile using a contact reference field? I have tried both and get errors on the import even though the format of the text is correct and those fields do not appear on the profile when doing a batch update. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that the referenced fields are imported as the same type.  Even if it is you use a name lookup for Contact , CiviCRM will need the Contact ID.

Also watch the date format, I prefer YYYYMMDD as that always works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Contact Import should work for contact reference fields, I did a quick test against 4.6 and it works as expected.

Currently batch update for contact reference fields is not supported in 4.6 or below version of CiviCRM.

Comment: I am using CiviCRM 4.5.8 and WP 4.1. To make sure I had fields right I exported from Civi first for one contact so the format was right. And the error I get is: Invalid value for field(s): but it was as taken from export. Thought?